# CSS style not apply to second dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I created 2 same dropdown menu in navigation bar. When point to main menu, the sub menu will auto display. And when scroll down, the background for sub menu will auto changed to white color. But it only affect in first sub menu, the sub menu for second main menu is not. I am calling same class, but why the css not apply to second sub menu? Below is my sample code.

```js
/**
 * cbpAnimatedHeader.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function () {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
            header = document.querySelector('.navbar-default'),
            subheader = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
            didScroll = false,
            changeHeaderOn = 150;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
            if (!didScroll) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout(scrollPage, 250);
            }
        }, false);
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if (sy >= changeHeaderOn) {
            classie.add(header, 'navbar-shrink');
            classie.add(subheader, 'navbar-shrink');
        } else {
            classie.remove(header, 'navbar-shrink');
            classie.remove(subheader, 'navbar-shrink');
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

```html
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50282572/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50282572/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body id="index" class="index-page" style="height:1000px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container" style="" id="">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li class="hidden" id="">
            <a href="#page-top" class="" target="" data-value=""></a>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown" id="listory">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Menu 1
<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class=""><a href="index.php?page=story1" class="page-scroll" target="" data-value="">White Color When scroll</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             Menu 2
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="" id=""><a href="logout.php" class="page-scroll" target="" data-value="">White Color When scroll</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div style="height:500px;background:blue;"></div>
<script src="http://demo.sc.chinaz.com/Files/DownLoad/moban/201511/moban810/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.sc.chinaz.com/Files/DownLoad/moban/201511/moban810/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.sc.chinaz.com/Files/DownLoad/moban/201511/moban810/js/classie.js"></script>
</body>
```

**View in full page to see the navigation menu**

Screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Comment: in your code snippet it works for both

Comment: @Johannes,If main menu is working. When you point to second main menu, the sub menu will show. Then when you scroll down the page, the background of sub menu is transparent, it should be same as first sub menu, which is white color background.

Comment: not here, really! It has a white background on hover and looks exactly as the first sub menu (hovered). Strange... (I am on Firefox 42, but it's the same on Chrome, I just checked.) I can't post a screenshot here, I suppose...

Comment: @Johannes, screenshot added.

Comment: I really can't tell you why, but it doesn't look like that here - it looks as you describe how it _should_ look.  hmm, mysterious...

Comment: see screenshot in "answer" below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it by myself. Thanks @Johannes and @Aminesrine for the tips. Previous code unable to handle multiple element with same class name. I just changed the js as below by added loop to check, and it's worked.

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function () {

var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector('.navbar-default'),
        subheader = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu'),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 150;

function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
        if (!didScroll) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout(scrollPage, 250);
        }
    }, false);
}

function scrollPage() {
    var sy = scrollY();
    if (sy >= changeHeaderOn) {
        classie.add(header, 'navbar-shrink');

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < subheader.length; i++) {
            classie.add(subheader[i], 'navbar-shrink');
        }
    } else {
        classie.remove(header, 'navbar-shrink');

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < subheader.length; i++) {
            classie.remove(subheader[i], 'navbar-shrink');
        }
    }
    didScroll = false;
}

function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}

init();

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This style

```
.navbar-default .nav-justified li {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

is applied correctly to the two sub-menu, just the first sub menu has an additional style:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.dropdown-menu.navbar-shrink {
background-color: #fff;
margin: 0;
}
```

if you delete the white background from this style you will notice that the 2 sub-menu will get the same style.
The first sub-menu `ul` has an an extra class `navbar-shrink`.

**edit :**

So you want `navbar-shrink` class to be added to 2 sub-menu, the problem is on the js code, you can replace

```
classie.add(header, 'navbar-shrink');
```

with

```
$('.dropdown-menu').addClass('navbar-shrink');
```

probably

```
header = document.querySelector('.navbar-default');
classie.add(header, 'navbar-shrink');
```

is selecting only the first occurence of the class, and not all class occurences.

```js
/**
 * cbpAnimatedHeader.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function () {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
            header = document.querySelector('.navbar-default'),
            subheader = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
            didScroll = false,
            changeHeaderOn = 150;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
            if (!didScroll) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout(scrollPage, 250);
            }
        }, false);
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if (sy >= changeHeaderOn) {
            classie.add(header, 'navbar-shrink');
            $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('navbar-shrink');
        } else {
            classie.remove(header, 'navbar-shrink');
            classie.remove(subheader, 'navbar-shrink');
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

```html
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50282572/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50282572/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body id="index" class="index-page" style="height:1000px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container" style="" id="">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li class="hidden" id="">
            <a href="#page-top" class="" target="" data-value=""></a>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown" id="listory">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Menu 1
<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class=""><a href="index.php?page=story1" class="page-scroll" target="" data-value="">White Color When scroll</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             Menu 2
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="" id=""><a href="logout.php" class="page-scroll" target="" data-value="">White Color When scroll</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div style="height:500px;background:blue;"></div>
<script src="http://demo.sc.chinaz.com/Files/DownLoad/moban/201511/moban810/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.sc.chinaz.com/Files/DownLoad/moban/201511/moban810/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.sc.chinaz.com/Files/DownLoad/moban/201511/moban810/js/classie.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what i want is add the additional style to second sub menu too. And why the class "navbar-shrink" won't auto added to second sub menu, since both code are same

Comment: Sry, I am new to javascript. But I used same class ".dropdown-menu" for both dropdown menu. It won't auto apply as long as same class? How do I fixed that? Thx

Comment: you can run the code snippet I have added, I think this is what you want

Comment: Incorrect, the default color for sub menu should be transparent. Only change to white when scroll down

Answer (score 1):

The javascript not adding class `navbar-shrink` to the second `.dropdown-menu` is definitely the reason.

If you *can* access and alter the script you quoted in the question, try to change this line

```
subheader = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
```

to this:

```
subheader = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu'),
```

Comment: PLEASE NOTE (EDIT): I removed the dot in `('.dropdown-menu')` in the last line!

Comment: Not working, and error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" in line "elem.classList.add(c);"